# How a war file gets deployed in any application server?

Tags: java, application-server

I know that when a war file is created of my web application, i have to deploy it, that is if i am using JBoss i have to copy it to deploy folder and if using WAS i have to install it.
But i want to know, When i start the server from where the server starts deploying my application. that is which is the entry point to start loading my classes, properties ,DB connections etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `web.xml` file, which is known as the deployment descriptor.  This is where you configure your servlets and filters.  In particular, you map urls to servlets, and this is the entry point into your application.  The classes are loaded on startup, before any requests are handled.

Here is a [link](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml.html) to more information about deployment descriptors.